# How safe to run Lighthouse without --auto-register vs. the effects of registering more than once?

Tags: lighthouse, slashings, validators, staking

Running a Lighthouse validator presents a message to strongly consider running `--auto-register` the first time.

The documentation also states:

> The --auto-register flag registers your signing key with the slashing
>   protection database, which keeps track of all the messages your
>   validator signs. This flag should be used sparingly, as reusing the
>   same key on multiple nodes can lead to your validator getting slashed.
>   On subsequent runs you should leave off the --auto-register flag.

Ideally, the flag is run exactly 1 time. But what happens if it's run 0 or 2+ times?

1. What are the risks by not using `--auto-register` at all?
2. Assuming `--auto-register` was run once already, what bad things will happen if Lighthouse is stopped, and then restarted with `--auto-register` (accidentally) again? An example of this happening is a Lighthouse crash and then restarting it with an old command history.